# Why not working request to deployment via service request and via ingress request?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

Install minikube version: v1.29.0 on MacOs.

I create API endpoint on flask and build in docker image

```
FROM debian:latest

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:5001", "--protocol=http", "-w", "wsgi:app", "--ini", "wsgi.ini"]
```

after load docker image into minikube

```
minikube image load drnoreg/devops_blog:0.0.1
```

check minikube

```
% minikube image ls 

docker.io/drnoreg/devops_blog:0.0.1
```

create deployment, service and ingress yaml

**app.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: devops-blog
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: devops-blog
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: devops-blog
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: devops-blog
          image: docker.io/drnoreg/devops_blog:0.0.1
          ports:
            - name: pod-port
              containerPort: 5001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: devops-blog
  labels:
    run: devops-blog
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: pod-port
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    run: devops-blog
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: devops-blog
  namespace: devops-blog
spec:
  rules:
    - host: devops-blog.cluster.local
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: devops-blog
                port:
                  number: 5001
```

execute create namespace

```
kubectl create namespace devops-blog
```

set current namespace

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=devops-blog
```

and create deployment, service and ingress

```
kubectl create -f app.yaml
```

after try forwarding port for check working flask API

```
kubectl port-forward devops-blog-f666d8cd7-njp95  5001:5001
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5001 -> 5001
Forwarding from [::1]:5001 -> 5001
Handling connection for 5001
Handling connection for 5001
```

flask API service in minikube **is working**.

```
% kubectl get service -n devops-blog -o wide
NAME          TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
devops-blog   NodePort   10.99.37.126   <none>        5001:30001/TCP   45s   run=devops-blog
% kubectl get pod -n devops-blog -o wide
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
devops-blog-f666d8cd7-b9n7j   1/1     Running   0          57s   10.244.0.34   minikube   <none>           <none>
% kubectl get node -n devops-blog -o wide
NAME       STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
minikube   Ready    control-plane   16h   v1.26.1   192.168.49.2   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS   5.10.47-linuxkit   docker://20.10.23
```

Now I try to check working API via minikube service

```
 % telnet 192.168.49.2 30001
Trying 192.168.49.2...
```

not working

add to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 devops-blog.cluster.local
```

try to check working API via ingress minikube

```
% telnet devops-blog.cluster.local 80   
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

not working too.

Why not working request to deployment via service request and via ingress request?
How solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In case you did not enable the ingress addon try enable it by executing the following command

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
```

Instead of **NodePort** service try using the **clusterIP** service for the app and when you are creating ingress you can give this service as backend like this

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: devops-blog
  labels:
    run: devops-blog
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: pod-port
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: devops-blog
```

**ingres.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: devops-blog
  namespace: devops-blog
  annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" #Since you are using localhost
spec:
  rules:
    - host: devops-blog.cluster.local
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: devops-blog
                port:
                  number: 5001
            path: /
```

Once the ingress is generated the IP try opening it in local browser with `http://devops-blog.cluster.local/`  or curl it like curl $ `curl http://devops-blog.cluster.local/`.

**Note:** In case you are deploying this app in the cloud try **LoadBalancer** as a service.

Try this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-g9r8BSlDFI) as it explained in detail

Comment: install and check % minikube addons list -> ingress                     | minikube | enabled ✅   | Kubernetes                     |
| ingress-dns                 | minikube | enabled ✅   | Google             try % curl http://devops-blog.cluster.local/                       
curl: (7) Failed to connect to devops-blog.cluster.local port 80: Connection refused

Comment: Did you try changing Nodeport to clusterIP. If possible can you update the question with latest configurations you used?